# Assistance needed - How to exit a for loop inside an if statement?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to run a for loop inside an if statement but it keeps repeating. I basically want pin 4 to blink 6 times when I press a button on pin 2. When z becomes a 6 in the for loop, the if statement makes it so that z is reset to 0 and the for loop restart all over again. Therefore the LED on pin 4 keeps blinking on and on. Anyone can help so that it blinks only 6 times? Here is the code:

```
int switchState = 0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);

}

void loop() 
{
  switchState = digitalRead(2);
  if (switchState == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    for (int z=0; z<6; z++)
    {
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      delay(100);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I cannot see a mistake in your code. The loop() method will get called again and again. Each time, it will check your button. If your button isn't pressed, pin 4 and 5 are set to low (i think this will be two LEDs which will be turned off), if it is pressed, pin 5 is turned on permanetly and pin 4 will be switched on and off 6 times, then loop() will start again.
There is nothing wrong with your z, there is no `the if statement makes it so that z is reset to 0 and the for loop restart all over again`.

Comment: Hey Markus,
my goal is to have the LED on pin 4 to blink 6 times and then stop blinking even though the button is held down. I would want the pin 5 to stay on, and would have to let go the button and press again for the pin 4 to start blinking again 6 times..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this:

```
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{

  //Deactivate all leds
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);

  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) { //If the button is pressed... 
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

    //blink
    for (int z=0; z<6; z++)
    {
       digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
       delay(100);
       digitalWrite(4, LOW);
       delay(100);
    }

    while (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) { // Wait until release the button
       delay(10); 
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks a lot Arton!
I didn't realize it was in fact a pause I needed when exiting the for loop.